# Cannot use Maven Central Repository

Tags: maven-2

Even with the proxy setting in the ../.m2/setting.xml file cannot get access the maven central repository. Was told have to use the local repository. Wondering because of this limitation what would be a good way to get the local repository build and use thereby use Maven effectively?

Answer (score 4):

You (or your admin) can have your local repo mirror the central repo and set your settings.xml file to use your local repo as the mirror for everything (see the [Nexus repo documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) for what to put in your settings.xml). When you build, maven will attempt to pull all resources from your local repo; if they're not there, your repo will automatically pull them from central and store them. The next time you build, all artifacts will come from your local repo and not central.